# Log Parser 2.2 separator

Tags: csv, separator, logparser

> Jan 1 22:54:17 drop   %LOGSOURCE% >eth1 rule: 7; rule_uid: {C1336766-9489-4049-9817-50584D83A245}; src: 70.77.116.190; dst: %DSTIP%; proto: tcp; product: VPN-1 & FireWall-1; service: 445; s_port: 2612;

This is the 1st entry in the log file. How do I use log parser to separate into columns by ';' as the separator?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the TSV input format specifying ';' as the separator:

```
logparser "SELECT * from thatlog.txt" -i:TSV -iSeparator:;
```

You might also want to play with the `nFields` option if you know in advance the number of fields. Lookup the TSV input format options:

```
logparser -h -i:TSV
```

Comment: Keep in mind that there are not text quotes in TSV. So multiline text can't be displayed with TSV. CSV can handle this but there is no way to specify the separator.